# Need a line of Code that will spit out a random string of specified characters

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am working in notepad, and a need a line of code that will spit out a random line of characters (that I specify). I need to be able change the number characters also.

Can anyone help?

Comment: what do you need this for exactly?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. You want to specify a set of lines, and have the code return one of them? Why is notepad relevant?

Comment: Please provide an example of how you might use that 'line of code' and what output you would expect.

Comment: Call me nerdy, but I'm making a Matrix. I can already do it with numbers as %random%, but I need letters too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm really not sure what exactly you're asking, but maybe you want a batch file that spits out a line of random characters, and here's a script that will do that.

Example output:

```
C:\>rand_chars
XF3KqsBIFzi
C:\>rand_chars
UNx1eQ8MebihmizfIjHT4gc7O85uIOxBk5u8xZj8pnBBOf0jSygII4kNx7IUJA8nMchRKl1f6sQgJjB
```

Code:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Change these values to whatever you want, or change the code to take them
REM as command-line arguments.  You must set CHARS_LEN to the string length
REM of the string in the CHARS variable.
REM 
REM This script generates a string of these characters at least
REM MIN_CHARS_IN_LINE chars long and at most MAX_CHARS_IN_LINE chars long.

SET CHARS=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
SET /A CHARS_LEN=26 + 26 + 10
SET /A MIN_CHARS_IN_LINE=5
SET /A MAX_CHARS_IN_LINE=79

REM Pick a random line length and output a random character until we reach that
REM length.

call:rand %MIN_CHARS_IN_LINE% %MAX_CHARS_IN_LINE%
SET /A LINE_LENGTH=%RAND_NUM%

SET LINE=
for /L %%a in (1 1 %LINE_LENGTH%) do (
    call:rand 1 %CHARS_LEN%
    SET /A CHAR_INDEX=!RAND_NUM! - 1
    CALL SET EXTRACTED_CHAR=%%CHARS:~!CHAR_INDEX!,1%%
    SET LINE=!LINE!!EXTRACTED_CHAR!
)
echo !LINE!

goto:EOF

REM The script ends at the above goto:EOF.  The following are functions.

REM rand()
REM Input: %1 is min, %2 is max.
REM Output: RAND_NUM is set to a random number from min through max.
:rand
SET /A RAND_NUM=%RANDOM% * (%2 - %1 + 1) / 32768 + %1
goto:EOF
```

Comment: sorry for bumming you out, but for some reason, it didn't work. Any revisions you can make?

Comment: Why the `extract_char()` function is so complicated? Couldn't it be just `SET EXTRACTED_CHAR=%1; SET EXTRACTED_CHAR=!EXTRACTED_CHAR:~%2,1!`?

Comment: I don't even see why use a dedicated function at all. You could simply apply the index directly to `CHARS`.

Comment: @CodeKid1001:  You're going to have to be a lot more specific than "it didn't work".

Comment: @Andriy M:  If you mean like `SET EXTRACTED_CHAR=!CHARS:~!CHAR_INDEX!,1!` inside the main loop, it doesn't work and you end up with the string literal `CHAR_INDEX` actually appearing in the output.  Maybe I just don't know the syntax.  So that made me think that variables weren't allowed in the substring operation, so I made `extract_char` rather complicated to work around it.  But your improvement does work inside a function, so I've edited my post, and thanks!  Probably batch has a problem with delayed-expansion variables as indexes, but not "regular" ones, so `%2` works.

Comment: @Indiv: The trick is, that first the index has to be expanded before the rest expands, it only depends on the expansion order, first `%var%` expands then `%%a` (For-Loop-Vars) and at last the `!var!`, and a call is executed after all, so that something like `call set char=%%chars:~%index%,1%%` or `set char=!chars:~%index%,1!` also works.

Comment: @Indiv: Maybe something like this: `CALL SET EXTRACTED_CHAR=^!CHARS:~!CHAR_INDEX!,1^!`?

Comment: @Indiv: My previous suggestion will probably not work, but this should: `CALL SET EXTRACTED_CHAR=%%CHARS:~!CHAR_INDEX!,1%%`.

Comment: @jeb, @Andriy M:  Thanks!  I've updated my code to remove the function.  One of these days I'll get the hang of the expansion order. ;)

Comment: @Indiv: (1st comment) When I put it in, a command prompt window came up with a line of something on it, but it disappeared before I could read it. This happened every time.     Thanks for the edit, I will try it when I get home.